# Whats an ideal way to share functionality between apps in Android?

Tags: android

I have moved from an iOS background to Android recently. My usecase is following.

I want to build a suite of apps. Each app needs to make server calls or do database operations. I do not want to write the code in each app of mine to do these operations.

So, I want to build a framework of my own which has API's exposed to do server and DB operations. Now, I can just import this framework in my applications and do server/DB operations.

In iOS this could be achieved by building a static library. How can similar thing be achieved in Android? 
Initially I was thinking about services but If I am not wrong they are specific to only an application and can not be shared among different applications.

Comment: Check the @CommonsWare anser too. It will hep

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can similar thing be achieved in Android?

Create and use [a library module](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html#LibraryModules).

> Initially I was thinking about services but If I am not wrong they are specific to only an application and can not be shared among different applications.

Services can be exported from one app and used by other apps.

A library is a compile-time construct. You are saying that you want one copy of the code on your development machine, but each app incorporates that code and uses it independently of other apps.

A service is a run-time construct. Here you are saying that you want one copy of the code running on a given device, and that other apps should talk to that one running copy of the code to perform various operations. This *greatly* increases the complexity of your apps and the coupling between them, and so using a service is not a simple substitute for using a library.

Comment: Thanks! I will go ahead with library modules. Looks like the thing I wanted. Simpler and easier to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

You're wrong about `Services`, I have a scenario where I communicate to same web server in each application.

So instead of writing same `service` in each application, I wrote one standalone service application which will expect my all application to `Broadcast` a message (depends on scenario). I exposed my database to `service` through `ContentProvider`. So my `service` know my application data. I achieved this successfully. Also you can use library module. You can know more from this [link](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html#LibraryModules)

Hope it give some idea.

Comment: thanks! this is also an option for me. How well does it handle the simultaneous call for same task from different applications? Library module has an advantage there  I suppose.

Comment: To handle this conflict I used `IntentService`